# How to show a next icon when clicking on a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, image

How to show a next button when click on a checkbox and it should be hidden when unclick?

For the first time it will not show image when unclick and shows image when clicks on checkbox

My code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   function showNext()
   {
     document.getElementById('displayImage').style.visibility='visible';
   }


 </script>
```

and

```
<img id="displayImage" border="0" src="icons/next1.png" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

the problem is that it will not hide the next icon after deselecting the checkbox..

Will it possible to use if condition inside javascript? If yes please explain..

ie: if checkbox is checked then show image

else

does not show image.

Help appreciated.....

Comment: Yes, JavaScript has an `if` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement

Comment: Thank you Felix.I got solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function showNext()
{
    var icon = document.getElementById('displayImage');
    icon.style.visibility = icon.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Yes.Realy this is what i was looking for.Thank you Mr Igor Dymov for the quick reply and help.

Comment: But the link seems to be present at the div tag.HOw could i also disable that??

Comment: <a href="index.php?next=systemcheck"><div><img id="displayImage" border="0" src="icons/next1.png" style="visibility:hidden" /></div></a>

Comment: if you do not use jQuery, try to operate with `icon.parentNode.parentNode` element

Comment: Igor Dymov i got solution..

I changed above line in to
 
<div>
<a href="index.php?next=systemcheck">
<img id="displayImage" border="0" src="icons/next1.png" style="visibility:hidden" />
</div>
</a>

Thank you for help